# Drawing a bitmap to the canvas of a text-view

Tags: android, performance, optimization, bitmap, android-canvas

I have a text-view and a bitmap.
Now, I want to draw this bitmap on the canvas of the text-view.
Is there any way I can obtain the canvas of the text-view, to draw the bitmap onto it ?

I know, I can achieve similar results by wrapping the bitmap into a bitmapdrawable, & setting the background of the text-view to this bitmapdrawable like this:
textView.setBackground(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap));
This operation needs to take place while UI interaction, so I do not want to do this way, as it requires creation of a bitmapdrawable object every time, & android does not recommend creating objects during UI interaction.

Can anybody suggest some other way to achieve similar results, which has least overhead.
Or is there anyway I can get the canvas of the textview object I am working on & directly draw the bitmap onto it ?

If anybody has worked in this area before, please help !

Comment: Did you try overriding the onDraw method of the text view? You may draw the bitmap on canvas there.

Comment: @Ercan I will need to extend the textview class to acheive this, as Rajesh CP suggested, but I do not want to do this, as I am working with legacy code, which uses text view object. Do you know of any other way, I can acheive this ?

Answer (score 1):

`extend` the `TextView` `Class` and `override` the `onDraw` method

```
Protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    super.onDraw(canvas);
}
```

Did not tested out the code. But this would be the way I would be going with.

Comment: Yes, we can do this way I think, but the issue is - I am working with legacy code, which is using a text-view, and I do not want to change it to be using an extended text-view class object everywhere in code, as that would be a huge change. Is there any other way, I can handle this ?

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. If you extend the TextView and override the onDraw, you will draw the bitmap without any text.